# How can you rephrase the following sentence to not end in "with"?

Tags: prepositions, sentence, complex-sentences

**I turned down the university's acceptance in order to find a program whose professors I more closely identify *with*.**

In the above sentence, it is difficult to figure our whether "with" is being used as part of a phrasal verb or a preposition. I know it is not best practice to end a sentence in prepositions, but even if this "with" is not a preposition, it makes the sentence seem strange.

Also, I chose "whose" because it sounds even worse to say:

I turned down the university's acceptance in order to find a program **with** professors I more closely identify *with*.

And in this last example it wouldn't sound right to just leave off the last "with."

Comment: It's a complete myth that you shouldn't end a sentence with a preposition. People who claim that are just repeating it by rote. (And I actually personally prefer the second version of the sentence, although I find nothing wrong with the first either.)

Comment: "I know it is not best practice to end a sentence in prepositions" Absolutely not true. Never has been.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is no longer fashionable to avoid prepositional endings the effort to avoid doing so is a good exercise in editing and word shuffling. If you find a proposition at the end you can throw it on the other side of the item to which it is pointing. In this case the professors.

I turned down the university's acceptance in order to find a program *with whose* professors I could more closely identify.

Of the prohibition to ending sentences with a preposition Churchill said it was a rule "Up with which I will not put!"